# Как с помощью Jquery активировать анимацию в определённом месте лэндинга, когда контент появится на экране?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Сейчас только изучаю анимацию на живой задаче. Поиск по сети не даёт желаемых результатов, поэтому параллельно с поиском задаю вопрос. Интересует механизм. Если можете подсказать его здесь - отлично. Если знаете хорошую ссылку - тоже неплохо.

Comment: Думаю, что это очень полезный кейс.

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstDivPosition = $('#first_div').position();
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() == firstDivPosition.top) {
       $('#second_div').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Я не вижу механизма, активизирующего анимацию в нужном месте страницы, когда пользователь до неё прокрутит. Меня именно это интересует.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom

Comment: У меня есть обрывки информации на тему, но мне нужно собрать это воедино, плюс может чего-то не дорыл ещё ...

Comment: О, спасибо, буду изучать.

Comment: А прочим гостям страницы буду так же признателен, если чего-то здесь подскажете :)

Comment: поправил ответ выше

Comment: Спасибо, дружище ! По ссылке на англоязычный стэк как раз об этом речь и идёт.